# Node.js socket read() like Java?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, sockets

While trying to port some socket code from Java to Node.js (or rather, node-webkit) I came to the part where a handshake is performed between the client and the server. The Java code for this is simple (validation left out):

```
    // C0
    byte C0 = 0x03;
    out.write(C0);

    // C1
    long timestampC1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    byte[] randC1 = new byte[1528];
    rand.nextBytes(randC1);

    out.writeInt((int)timestampC1);
    out.writeInt(0);
    out.write(randC1, 0, 1528);
    out.flush();

    // S0
    byte S0 = (byte)in.read();
    if (S0 != 0x03)
        throw new IOException("Server returned incorrect version in handshake: " + S0);

    // S1
    byte[] S1 = new byte[1536];
    in.read(S1, 0, 1536);
```

I was wondering if there is any way in Node.js to do something similar to Java's  `Socket.read()`. I do not see any in the documentation, but it seems logical because Node.js is more asynchronous.

I have succeeded in writing the sending of the handshake (and confirmed that it works) using this code (methods for sending left out):

```
    //C0
    sendByte(sock, 0x03);

    //C1
    var ts = Date.now();
    sock.randomBytes = crypto.randomBytes(1528);
    sendInt(sock, ts);
    sendInt(sock, 0x0);
    sendBytes(sock, sock.randomBytes);
```

My first thought was to keep track of the connection state and to continue the handshake when a `data` event is received and the connection has the relevant state. However, the buffer that comes with the `data` event is limited to 1024 bytes, while the Java code is easily able to read 1528 bytes. The rest of the bytes seem to come in the next `data` call.

Should I be storing the contents from `data` in a Buffer and appending whenever the data is received or is there another (easier) way of doing this (a premade module, a method similar to `read`, ...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no synchronous `read()` in that same way, but what can you do in node is something like:

```
// using a helper function can help normalize things
function readSocket(socket, nb, cb) {
  var r = socket.read(nb);
  if (r === null) {
    socket.once('readable', function() {
      readSocket(socket, nb, cb);
    });
    return;
  }
  cb(r);
}

// read in 1 byte
readSocket(socket, 1, function(buf) {
  // `buf` is a Buffer with `buf.length === 1`
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing that this doesn't result in a stack overflow? Also, what prevents the `.once('readable', ...)` from calling itself over and over repeatedly and starving other processes/threads? (I'm new to web dev, as you can tell.)